# Assign random number in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, function, random, numbers

I have table in postgresql with statename, districtname and DistID . Now I want to assign random number(starting from 1 to count of district in a particular state) to the column 'DistID' for each district based on their states. Kindly help.

Comment: Do the numbers need to be unique within a particular state, and when you say random do you mean they need to be unpredictable or you just don't care what the numbers are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below will update the table so that each district is numbered within the state with values starting from 1.

The query assigns the IDs in a random order.  If you wanted predictable change random() to district and it will order them by district name alphabetically.

```
update t
set distid = v.distid
from (
select 
  statename, district, 
  row_number() over (partition by statename order by random()) as distid
from t) v
where v.statename = t.statename and v.district = t.district;
```

Fiddle example at
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/86341/5